# How to test on null value before using predefined methods in textField

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to concat different strings in a *textField*. So to prevent *NullPointerException*, I have to test if the string to concatinate is null.

```
 $F{ADET2}.concat($F{ADET4}).concat($F{ADET5}).concat($F{ADET6}).concat($F{ADET7}).concat($F{ADET8})
```

So how to write this in textField value :

```
  if ($F{ADET2}! = null )

   if ($F{ADET4}! = null )
      $F{ADET2}.concat($F{ADET4})
   if ($F{ADET5}! = null )
      $F{ADET2}.concat($F{ADET4}).concat($F{ADET4})
     ....
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Jasper-Reports thing, but can't you implement some looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*Joiner*](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class from [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained).

In your case the expression will be:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Joiner.on("").skipNulls().join(Arrays.asList($F{ADET2}, $F{ADET4}, $F{ADET5}, $F{ADET6}, $F{ADET7}, $F{ADET8}))]]></textFieldExpression>
```

---

***Notes***:

- Don't forget to add import and add *guava* to classpath:

```xml
<import value="com.google.common.base.Joiner"/>
```

- I've set report's language as *Java*
- You can also use [ternary operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29) for solving this task.

Comment: This also works using the ternary operator like you said in your previous comment :                                                    $F{ADET2}!=null ? ($F{ADET2}.concat($F{ADET3}!=null ?  $F{ADET3} :"" ).concat( $F{ADET4}!=null ?  $F{ADET4} :"").concat( $F{ADET5}!=null ?  $F{ADET5} :"").concat($F{ADET6} != null ? $F{ADET6} : "").concat($F{ADET7}!= null ? $F{ADET7} : "").concat($F{ADET8} != null ? $F{ADET8} : "")) : ""

Comment: Yes, but this solution is better, IMHO